# getClass() not working?

Tags: java, compareto

```
public int compareTo(Object a) {  
    int Output = 0;  
    if(this.equals(a))  
        Output = 0;  
    if(a instanceof this.getClass()) {  
        if(this._numDec > ((this.getClass())a)._numDec)   
        Output = 1;  
        if(this._numDec < ((this.getClass())a)._numDec)   
        Output = -1;  
    }  
    return Output;  
}
```

Hello. My CS instructor told our class to create a function that would determine which of the two values would be larger, outputting 1 if the former is larger, 0 if they are equal, and -1 if the former is smaller. The `this.getClass()` was originally a Hexadecimal class for converting Hexadecimal values into _numDec. However, I get errors when I try to use this.getClass(). Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

Write out the exact class name explicitly.

```
if (a instanceof Hexadecimal) {  
    if (this._numDec > ((Hexadecimal) a)._numDec)   
        Output = 1;  
    if (this._numDec < ((Hexadecimal) a)._numDec)   
        Output = -1;  
}
```

By the way, if `a` is not a `Hexadecimal` object then your method is going to return 0. It should return non-zero.

Comment: John Kugelman, I'm trying to make this work for all classes of different bases. So this is supposed to work for Binary as well as Hexadecimal but I don't want to write it out twice which is why I'm asking if there was a way for me to use .getClass()

Comment: @user1844067 Do `Binary` and `Hexadecimal` have a common base class? If so, put the compareTo method there and use that class's name.

Comment: No but they do both share the _numDec integer. My teacher said we were working under the assumption that the two types have the same class so I wanted to use this.getClass() on the first object to use on the second object in place of the Hexadecimal that you are suggesting I put in.

Answer (score 0):

You are not having problems because your call to `getClass()` isn't working, you are having problems because you are using incorrect casting syntax. The correct syntax is of the form:

```
<type> target_var = (<type>) source_var;
```

Where `<type>` is expected to be an actual Java type (primitive or object). Valid Java primitive types are (int, float, long, double, char, boolean ...). Valid object types are specified by their fully qualified name, or simple name if the type is imported. For example (String, Serializable, Object, JFrame ...).

In your code, this line:

```
if(this._numDec > ((this.getClass())a)._numDec)
```

Will not compile because you are specifying the casting  to be `this.getClass()`, which is a dynamic expression, not a valid type.

There are several ways to accomplish your ***real*** goal, which is too determine if the supplied object is of a type that you can compare to the current object, and then to perform the comparison. Here's one such way:

```
if(a instanceof Binary)) {
    if(this.getNumDec() > ((Binary)a).getNumDec())   
        Output = 1;  
    else 
        Output = -1;  
} else if(a instanceof Hexadecimal) {
    if(this.getNumDec() > ((Hexadecimal)a).getNumDec())
        Output = 1;
    else
        Output = -1;
}
```

Note that I have replaced the use of direct property access with accessor methods.